# can't use javascript to hide & show elements from list

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a collapsable li so I want to show a paragraph on clicking the li(index) i searched for a while and found that you can target the li by using onClick function and i succeeded to hide the paragraph but when after clicking again on the li(index) the paragraph not showing any more is there any one can help me?

```js
function myfunction(li) {
  var TextInsideLi = li.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

  if (TextInsideLi.style.display = "block") {
    TextInsideLi.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    TextInsideLi.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="questions" id="myList">
  <li class="question" onclick="myfunction(this)">
    <div class="question-header">
      <a>What types of licenses are included?</a>
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="question" onclick="myfunction(this)">
    <div class="question-header">
      <a>What types of licenses are included?</a>
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `if(TextInsideLi.style.display = "block")`must be `if(TextInsideLi.style.display === "block")`. You are assigning instead of comparing.

Comment: Aside from answering your question I've also covered several best practice violations your code has in my answer. Check it out to learn more than only how to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earlier answer only works on the second click of `li`, the answer below works on the first click.

You were doing assignment earlier in the `if` statement, you need to use `==` or another comparison operator rather than an assignment operator.

Also I check for if the display is not none rather than if it is block since initially it has neither block or none.

```js
function myfunction(li) {
  var TextInsideLi = li.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
  
  console.log("click");

  if (TextInsideLi.style.display !== "none") {
    TextInsideLi.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    TextInsideLi.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="questions" id="myList">
  <li class="question" onclick="myfunction(this)">
    <div class="question-header">
      <a>What types of licenses are included?</a>
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="question" onclick="myfunction(this)">
    <div class="question-header">
      <a>What types of licenses are included?</a>
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are *assigning* instead of *comparing*:

```
if(TextInsideLi.style.display = "block")
```

must be

```
if(TextInsideLi.style.display === "block")
```

Also, on the initial click, your `p` element does not have any inline styles (which element.style checks for ***only***). That is why in one of the answers initially you have to click twice.

I suggest you work with the existing, universal `hidden` API instead.

As well as avoiding inline styles, you should also try to avoid inline event listeners like `onclick="..."`. Instead, work with `addEventListener`.

```js
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('li.question');

for (const question of questions) {
  question.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pElement = question.querySelector('p:last-child');
    pElement.hidden = !pElement.hidden; // toggles el.hidden
  });
}
```

```html
<ul class="questions" id="myList">
  <li class="question" onclick="myfunction(this)">
    <div class="question-header">
      <a>What types of licenses are included?</a>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="question" onclick="myfunction(this)">
    <div class="question-header">
      <a>What types of licenses are included?</a>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for helping me i wish you all the best man

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a compare instead of assignment '='

```
if (TextInsideLi.style.display === "block")
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and just made a comparison like so:

if (TextInsideLi.style.display **===** "block") with 3 '=' symbols.

It worked for me.